# Why is while loop treated true if condition is false?

Tags: java

I am trying to do in Java:

```
int i=5;
while(i-- >0) {
   System.out.println(i);

}
```

When running this program the output is:

```
4
3
2
1
0
```

I am very surprised to see `0` in output. I am new in development. Can anyone justify this?

Comment: Ahh, `-->`, the good old [goes to operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Postdecrement/Increment** operator works on the principle **"Use first and then Change"**

Initially value of i=5, when it enters while loop it will compare value of i first and then it prints the decremented value. Here i will show you each iteration along with checks performed in each iteration,

1. Now value of i=5(in memory), inside while(5>0), it prints 4.
2. Now value of i=4(in memory), inside while(4>0), it prints 3.
3. Now value of i=3(in memory), inside while(3>0), it prints 2.
4. Now value of i=2(in memory), inside while(2>0), it prints 1.
5. Now value of i=1(in memory), inside while(1>0), it prints 0.

Hope now you are clear to go ahead. Gud Luck.

Answer (score 5):

In your `while` condition `i-- > 0`, the variable `i` is evaluated *first* and then decremented.

When `i` reaches the value `1`, it will pass the loop test and then get decremented to `0`.  This is why the print statement shows `0` in the output.

Here is a mnemonic you can use to keep track of how the decrement and increment operators work:

```
int i = 5;
System.out.println("When i = 5 then:");
System.out.println("i-- is " + i--);
i = 5;
System.out.println("--i is " + --i);
```

**Output:**

```
When i = 5 then:
i-- is 5
--i is 4
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply, because you compare `i>0` and decrement `i` afterwards.

```
// If I is 1, you compare 1>0 and decrement i afterwards.
// This is how the postdecrement operator works
while(i-- >0) {
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

the loop will behave like the following.

```
is i=5 > 0?
decrement i to 4
output i = 4.
is i=4 > 0?
decrement i to 3
output i = 3.
...
and so on
```

As you can see the value you compare to `0` is allways higher then the one you are outputing. This happens due to how the `--` operator works. If it´s preceding to the `i` as `--i` it will decrement the variable `i` first and return it´s value afterwards. If it´s not preceding as in your case `i--` you will have the value of `i` returned first and `i` beeing decremented afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

The post-decrement operator `--` is ***like a post-paid service***. Like a credit card, first you use, then you pay.

I thought I can give you a real-life idea of what really is occurring in this statement, when `i == 1`

```
while(i-- >0)
```

So, first you check if `i(1)>0`. `1>0` So, yes it is. Right after this statement is done, `i` becomes 0. Then, you print that value.

Alternatively, you might also get this intuition by noticing that although your loop started with `i=5`, the value `5` never got printed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the post-decrement operator in the while loop, when `i` is 1, `i--` returns 1, and then inside the loop you get 0 when you print `i` for the last time.

Comment: Yes sir,
You get it coz today em only learning loops.

You are right i initialized to 5.

Answer (score 1):

Only because of post decrement operator `(i--)` will check the condition first then decrease the value of `i`. Output is giving such. Thank you

```
int i=5; //initialize with 5
while(i-- >0) { //post decrements operator so, check condition first then decrease the value. 
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

In first iteration of `while` loop will check `5 > 0` will be checked after that decrease the value of `i` and `i` will become `4` So, Print it `4` not `5`.

- When `i = 5` conditional statement will be `(5>0)` (**true**) and print `4`.
- `i = 4` conditional statement will be `(4>0)` (**true**) and print `3`.
- `i = 3` conditional statement will be `(3>0)` (**true**) and print `2`.
- `i = 2` conditional statement will be `(2>0)` (**true**) and print `1`.
- `i = 1` conditional statement will be `(1>0)` (**true**) and print `0`.

Now, `i` became `0` so conditional statement will be `(0>0)` (**False**).

So, loop exits.

Answer (score -2):

To get desired output try this

```
while(--i >0) {
   System.out.println(i);

}
```

Comment: He didn't ask for the 'corrected code', he asked to explain the current code

Comment: Still think it's useful to explain ways to change it, the OP might not have known about the post or pre decrement option.

Comment: @Stultuske comparing this, he can understand difference. Its not bad solution to downvote

Comment: @RaghuNagaraju it doesn't answer the question asked, so it isn't exactly a good 'answer'. sure, he can compare the two, but that doesn't mean he will understand it. He's looking for an explanation, not a solution.